# WP Multisite Subdirectory Custom Permalinks 404

Tags: permalinks, multisite

I'm running a Multisite Subdirectory setup with the following structure.

- Example.com/ (main site)
- Example.com/en-us

I'm trying to achieve the following using a custom structure in the permalink settings:

- Example.com/blog/postname
- Example.com/en-us/blog/postname

It works for the main site however it gives a 404 on the /en-us/ site.

I'm also running the latest version.

I must be missing something? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: do you have code? This stack is for developers, by asking here you're going to get a technical code based answer and it's assumed you're a programmer. If you're looking for a solution as a non-developer the .org support forums might be a better choice

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any code. It's just the default htaccess and config

Comment: that's unfortunate, if it's just non-technical help you're looking for you should go to the .org support forums, also `/blog` is a special keyword, be very careful with it